# Implement css hover to work for all <a> elements else one of them

Tags: html, css, hover

This is my css code:

```
#navigation
{
    width: 100%;
    height:31px;
    background:#333;
}
#navigation ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
#navigation li a
{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    color:#CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#navigation li a:hover
{
    color:#FFF;
}
```

And this is my html code:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><div><a href="">menu1</a></div></li>
        <li><div><a href="">menu2</a></div></li>
        <li><div><a href="">menu3</a></div></li>
        <li><div><a href="">menu4</a></div></li>   
      </ul>
</div>
```

Here every link tag has hover event. But I want to remove hover event for only menu1. I mean user can click on menu2, menu3 and menu4 but menu1 doesn't have hover event so when user click on it, nothing happen.

Comment: Your html is broken. See my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tzwHj)

```
#navigation
{
    width: 100%;
    height:31px;
    background:#333;
}
#navigation ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
#navigation li a
{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    color:#CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#navigation li:hover:nth-of-type(2) a
{
    color:#FFF;
}
#navigation li:hover:nth-of-type(3) a
{
    color:#FFF;
}
#navigation li:hover:nth-of-type(4) a
{
    color:#FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#navigation li:not(:first-child) a:hover
{
    color:#FFF;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr0ep1m7/)

Answer (score 1):

For selecting second elements and next, you can use `+` selector in CSS:

```
#navigation li + li a:hover
{
    color: #FFF;
}
```

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html):

> `E + F`: Matches any `F` element immediately preceded by a sibling element `E`.

For disabling the link, you should change your markup, or use JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks. What is this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a id or class to the first element (The one you dont want to hover)

Add this css to that class or id

```
#id-you-used:hover {
color: #CCC;
}

.class-you-used:hover {
color: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: In addition to that, there is no reason to have div tags inside your links. It's extra markup that isn't required and will increase load times of your site.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is broken for first two links

```
    <li><div><a href="">menu1/a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="">menu2/a></div></li>
```

should be :

```
    <li><div><a href="">menu1</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="">menu2</a></div></li>
```

Comment: Yes sorry I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

One other easy answer:

css code:

```
 @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}


#navigation
{
    width: 100%;
    height:31px;
    background:#333;
}
#navigation ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
#navigation li a
{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    color:#CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#username
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    color:#CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#078415;
}
#navigation a:hover
{
    color:#FFF;
}
```

html code:

```
<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><div id="username">menu1</div></li>
    <li><div><a href="">menu2</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="">menu3</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="">menu4</a></div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain how your two answers differ? They seem like duplicate posts, besides some minor changes to the html.

Answer (score 0):

One more easy answer:

css code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}


#navigation
{
    width: 100%;
    height:31px;
    background:#333;
}
#navigation ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navigation ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
#navigation li a
{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    color:#CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 10px; 
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#navigation a.active:hover
{
    color:#FFF;
}
```

html code:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li style="float:left; background-color:#055C06;"><div><a>menu1</a></div></li>
        <li style="float:left; background-color:#DA4A38;"><div><a class="active" href="">menu2</a></div></li>           
        <li><div><a class="active" href="">menu3</a></div></li>
        <li><div><a class="active" href="">menu4</a></div></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```